# Plasma TV wrong resolution

Tags: resolution, windows-8.1, plasma-tv

My tv's got a native resolution of 1024x768.
Windows 8.1 allow me to choose 2 values for the resolution: 1280x720 or 1920x1080.
Actually, when I put VLC in full screen mode, I can't see the volume bar.

How can I add more resolutions to find the right one for my tv?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that your TV's resolution is 1024x768? 1280x720 (aka 720p) or 1920x1080 (aka 1080p) are MUCH more common resolutions for TVs.

Comment: I've answered as best as I can, but a bit more info about your computer. TV Brand, PC Brand/Model and what type of hardware it has would be quite helpful.

Comment: I've got a Panasonic TH-42PV60EH, and I read the technical sheets at the end of the manual...

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible it's an [EDTV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced-definition_television) (Extended or Enchanced Definition TV), which somewhere in between SDTV and HDTV. They often meet the vertical pixel count for an HD image, but fall short in the horizontal pixel department.

You can generally add custom resolutions with your GPU driver control software. How you do that depends on what GPU your machine has.

**NVIDIA**

You can use this guide here: http://www.nvidia.com/object/custom_resolutions.html

- Browse to the NVIDIA Display Properties by right mouse clicking on the Windows desktop and selecting NVIDIA Display.

[image: Nvidia Custom Resolution]

- Select the Change Resolution option.

[image: Nvidia Custom Resolution 2]

- Click the Add button.
- Read and Accept the End User License Agreement.
- Type in the desired settings for a custom resolution.

[image: Nvidia Custom Resolution 3]

**AMD**

With AMD you use the Catalyst Control Centre, but they don't seem to have an official guide and the only machine I have with an AMD/ATI GPU is my HTPC which I currently don't have access to. However, the method should be very similar to way you set it up with NVIDIA.

I will update this portion of the answer when I have access to the HTPC.